# Python : Function which works on initial/default values if no parameters are passed

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, data-analysis

I have defined a function which calculates the mean of a column `Test 1` in my dataframe between two time limits.

The dataframe is -:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':[0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.68, 0.94, 1.25, 1.65, 1.88, 
2.05, 2.98, 3.45, 3.99, 4.06],'Test 1':[5, 9, 4, 6, 4, 1, 6, 8, 2, 9, 3, 9, 4]})
```

And the function is -:-

```
def custom_mean(x,y):
return df.loc[df['Time'].between(x,y), 'Test 1'].mean()
```

The function `custom_mean(x,y)` calculates the mean between the two time limits `x` and `y`. How can I define a function or write a piece of code which does exactly the same thing (calculates mean between two limits) when the parameters are passed and calculates the mean of whole column starting from the very first value till the last if no parameters are passed (e.g. mean of the values corresponding to the time limit from 0.00 to 4.06 in my dataframe)?

Comment: Do you mean that if x and y are not passed, you want to get mean of whole `Test 1` column?

Comment: Yes, I meant that if I do not enter any value of x and y in the parentheses, it should find the mean of whole column
    
   i.e. custom_mean() should yield the mean of whole column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the minimum and maximum values as the default:

```
def custom_mean(x=df.Time.min(), y=df.Time.max()):
    return df.loc[df['Time'].between(x,y), 'Test 1'].mean()
```

`custom_mean()` would then give `5.384615384615385`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set initial values to `None` for the function arguments like below:

```
def custom_mean(x=None, y=None):
    # if either of x or y is None, return the mean of whole column
    if x is None or y is None:
        return df['Test 1'].mean()
    # otherwise, filter and get mean
    return df.loc[df['Time'].between(x,y), 'Test 1'].mean()

>>> custom_mean()
5.384615384615385
>>> custom_mean(x=0.0, y=2.05)
5.0
>>> custom_mean(x=0.0, y=0.6)
6.0
```

Comment: I think this will not work if I pass only one parameter. Let's say if I want the mean from Time 2.0 till the last time limit and use custom_mean(2,), this will yield the mean of whole column instead of giving me the mean from 2 till last.

Comment: Well, it was not stated in your question clearly. This is what the OP states: `calculates the mean of whole column starting from the very first value till the last if no parameters are passed`. It doesn't specify that one could pass either x or y.